# Проблема с установкой ограничения при скрапинге сайта Python (Парсинг) на секцию html-страницы

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, bs4, web-scraping

Доброго времени суток.

Существует сайт со следующей архитектурой html страницы:

```html
<div class="card__container">
<div class="card">
<div class="card__title">Name</div>
<div class="card__name">
<span class="card__name-1">TEXT</span>
<span class="card__name-2">TEXT2</span>
</div>
```

Скрапинг выполняется посредством библиотеки bs4 для Telegram бота.

В решении используются все секции, но вопрос применяется только к "card__name-2"

Скрапинг происходит с помощью следующего кода:

```python
scrap = soup.find("div", class_="card__container").findAll("div", class_="card")[4].find("span", class_="card__name-2").get_text(strip=True) # Карточек много, поэтому используется только 5-я
```

В штатном режиме парсятся данные по типу: "+2", "+66" и т. д.
Но существует особенность сайта, по которой, если за день не произошло прибавок (т. е., если значение "+0"), то секция удаляется с html архитектуры.

Как обозначить ограничение, которое позволит указать "0", если секция отсутствует?

У самого возникают трудности из-за недостатка опыта, не имею представляю к чему приписывать ограничение

Если необходима эта информация, то вывод происходит через:

```python
name_text = f'{scrap}'
bot.send_message(chat_id, name_text, parse_mode='html')
```

Пример ошибки, которая приходит, если секция отсутствует:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду предельно благодарен за помощь. Всем добра :)

Comment: Если у того, кто пожелает оказать помощь возникнет необходимость в дополнительной информации по коду - укажите. Постарался сократить для максимальной простоты восприятия

Comment: пробуйте конструкция try - except для обработки исключений

Comment: Здраствуйте, Сергей.
Просмотрел документацию, помогло. Использовал try: *Условие* except AttributeError: *Результат = 0* . Установил к необходимым секциям. Благодарю за помощь, напишите ответ, отмечу, как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пробуйте конструкция try - except для обработки исключений